# How to use installed modules in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am using the skeleton-typescript sample and work through the documentation. I am trying to set up a value converter with numeral as it is shown in the [docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/binding/1.0.0-beta.1.3.2/doc/article/binding-value-converters/3).

```
import numeral from 'numeral';

export class CurrencyFormatValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return numeral(value).format('($0,0.00)');
  }
}
```

I have installed numeral via `jspm install numeral`. It is added package.json within the jspm dependencies and I manually added it to bundles.js.

After saving the typescript file I get the error: `Cannot find module 'numeral'.`. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be able to import it after installing via jspm. Perhaps there is an error somewhere in your code

Answer (score 3):

You need d.ts for numeral.js. and since there is no d.ts on Typings this can resolve problem:

```
$ jspm install npm:@types/numeral.
```

It works in my skeleton with value converters. Import can be done like `import * as numeral from 'numeral'`;

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in your configuration like:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin('numeral'); 

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

You will find the exact package names in your package.json:

```
jspm": {
   "dependencies": {
        ...
        "numeral": "xxxx"
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I already added the plugin call and double checked that package.json lists "numeral": "npm:numeral@^1.5.3" as jspm dependency. The error "Cannot find module 'numeral' is still there." VsCode is also complaining that it cannot find module numeral.